# SwipeCards not showing using custom adapter

Tags: android, firebase, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter, custom-adapter

I'm developing an app like tinder using this swipe card https://github.com/Diolor/Swipecards . I made a custom adapter which set data to swipecard. everything is fine i checked logcat where data printing. i checked logcat of getItemCount(). it showing data's size. my problem is data not showing in the swipecard.

**Update**

In this code there are two methods

1. getPeople() which is working perfectly, showing data to the swipe cards.
2. getNearbyPeople which is also working but data not showing in the swipe cards. both the methods using same codes and adapter. sometimes its shows data but takes too long time almost half an hour. one is working and another one doesn't. hope you understand what i said. thanks in advance.

**All codes are below**

**MainActivity.class**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


import com.firebase.geofire.GeoFire;
import com.firebase.geofire.GeoLocation;
import com.firebase.geofire.GeoQueryDataEventListener;
import com.firebase.geofire.core.GeoHash;
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationResult;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.lorentzos.flingswipe.SwipeFlingAdapterView;
import com.pk.tinder.R;
import com.pk.tinder.cards.Card;
import com.pk.tinder.cards.CardAdapter;
import com.pk.tinder.matches.MatchActivity;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    FusedLocationProviderClient client;
    private CardAdapter cardAdapter;
    ArrayList<Card> cardList;

    SwipeFlingAdapterView flingContainer;
    CardView cardViewAccountButton;
    CardView cardViewLike, cardViewDislike, cardViewSuperLike;

    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser;
    DatabaseReference mUsersDb;

    private String currentUid;
    private String userSex;
    private String oppositeUserSex;

    GeoFire geoFire;
    GeoLocation geoLocation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        flingContainer = findViewById(R.id.frame);

        cardList = new ArrayList<Card>();

        //firebase
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mFirebaseUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

        currentUid = mFirebaseUser.getUid();


        //database
        mUsersDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

        //location updates
        geoFire = new GeoFire(mUsersDb);
        client = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        final LocationRequest locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        locationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(100);
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

        client.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest,
                new LocationCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                        super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
                        if (locationResult != null) {
                            geoLocation = new GeoLocation(locationResult.getLastLocation().getLatitude(),
                                    locationResult.getLastLocation().getLongitude());

                            GeoHash geoHash = new GeoHash(geoLocation);

                            if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
                                DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users")
                                        .child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
                                ref.child("g").setValue(geoHash.getGeoHashString());
                                ref.child("l").child("0").setValue(geoLocation.latitude);
                                ref.child("l").child("1").setValue(geoLocation.longitude);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                Looper.getMainLooper())
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

                    }
                });
       //getPeople();
         showNearbyPeople();
        flingContainer.setAdapter(cardAdapter); 
}

//data fetching from firebase without location  
public void getPeople() {
        mUsersDb.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                Log.d("log", dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()){

                    Log.d("log", dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());

                    Card card;

                      card = new Card(dataSnapshot.child("account").child("name").getValue().toString(),
                                dataSnapshot.getKey(),
                                profileImageUrl);

                    cardList.add(card);
            cardAdapter = new CardAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.swipe_card_item, cardList);

                    cardAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Log.d("log386", String.valueOf(cardAdapter.getItemCount()));

                }         
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
    }


//data fetching through firebase with nearby location
    private void showNearbyPeople() {
        Log.d("loggeo", geoLocation.toString());
        geoFire.queryAtLocation(geoLocation, 5)
                .addGeoQueryDataEventListener(new GeoQueryDataEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataEntered(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, GeoLocation location) {
                        Card card = null;
                        if (dataSnapshot.exists(){

                            Log.d("log", dataSnapshot.toString());


                          card = new Card(dataSnapshot.child("account").child("name").getValue().toString(),
                                dataSnapshot.getKey(),
                                profileImageUrl);


                            Log.d("log 382", "Name :" + card.getName() + "key :" + card.getUid() + " url :" + card.getProfileImageUrl());
                            cardList.add(card);
                            cardAdapter = new CardAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.swipe_card_item, cardList);
                            cardAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            Log.d("log386", String.valueOf(cardAdapter.getItemCount()));

                            Log.d("log 387", "Name :" + cardList.get(0).getName() + "key :" + cardList.get(0).getUid() + " url :" + cardList.get(0).getProfileImageUrl());
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onDataExited(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onDataMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, GeoLocation location) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onDataChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, GeoLocation location) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onGeoQueryReady() {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onGeoQueryError(DatabaseError error) {
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

**CardAdapter.class**

```
public class CardAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Card> {

    private ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context context;

    public CardAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resourceId, ArrayList<Card> cards) {
        super(context, resourceId, cards);
        this.cards = cards;
        this.context = context;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NotNull ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.swipe_card_item, parent, false);
        }
        Card card = cards.get(position);

        Log.d("logsize", String.valueOf(getItemCount()));
        Log.d("logadapter", "Name :" + card.getName() + "uId :" + card.getUid() + "url :" + card.getProfileImageUrl());

        TextView textViewName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewFullName);
        ImageView imageViewPhoto = convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewPhoto);

        textViewName.setText(card.getName());

        Glide.with(getContext()).load(card.getProfileImageUrl()).centerCrop().into(imageViewPhoto);

        Log.d("log32", "Name :" + card.getName() + "uId :" + card.getUid() + "url :" + card.getProfileImageUrl());
        return convertView;
    }

    public int getItemCount() {
        return cards.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return super.getItemViewType(position);
    }
}
```

**Card.class**

```
public class Card {

    private String name;
    private String uid;
    private String profileImageUrl;
    private String location;

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public String getProfileImageUrl() {
        return profileImageUrl;
    }

    public void setProfileImageUrl(String profileImageUrl) {
        this.profileImageUrl = profileImageUrl;
    }

    public Card(String name, String uid, String profileImageUrl) {
        this.name = name;
        this.uid = uid;
        this.profileImageUrl = profileImageUrl;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getUid() {
        return uid;
    }

    public void setUid(String uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
    }
}
```

**swipe_card_item.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="16dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewPhoto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient1"
            android:padding="16dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|start"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewFullName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    tools:text="UserName" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="19"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Mumbai, India"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</FrameLayout>
```

**Logcat**

```
2019-11-23 13:20:41.409 16591-16656/com.pk.tindertest D/log375: Name :Sanjukey :UJykVjc9RuQNPPehHbbYZ0PpY8h1 url :https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/tinder-pk.appspot.com/o/profileImages%2FUJykVjc9RuQNPPehHbbYZ0PpY8h1?alt=media&token=3bf3130d-4940-4bef-904f-a520894f1d81
2019-11-23 13:20:41.410 16591-16656/com.pk.tindertest D/log377: Name :Menkakey :73iFRWoBcJW02m2W1QU1gW1glLH3 url :https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/tinder-pk.appspot.com/o/profileImages%2F73iFRWoBcJW02m2W1QU1gW1glLH3?alt=media&token=0ee8adc3-f483-41b9-910c-ef5017a98dfe
2019-11-23 13:20:41.410 16591-16656/com.pk.tindertest D/log381: 5
2019-11-23 13:20:45.011 16591-16617/com.pk.tindertest V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
2019-11-23 13:21:00.496 16591-16596/com.pk.tindertest I/zygote64: Do partial code cache collection, code=60KB, data=38KB
2019-11-23 13:21:00.496 16591-16596/com.pk.tindertest I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=60KB, data=38KB
2019-11-23 13:21:00.496 16591-16596/com.pk.tindertest I/zygote64: Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
2019-11-23 13:22:56.359 16591-16596/com.pk.tindertest I/zygote64: Do full code cache collection, code=123KB, data=82KB
2019-11-23 13:22:56.364 16591-16596/com.pk.tindertest I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=97KB, data=58KB
```

Comment: because you are setting the wrong adapter

Comment: after you add data to list call adapter.notifydatasetChanged()

Comment: @RituSumanMohanty i already have done but this didn't work for me

Comment: Set adapter inside onDataEntered method

Comment: hi try adding this line flingContainer.init(this, arrayAdapter)

Comment: @kam1234 and ritu both are not working for me

Comment: Add get count method in array adapter and check

Comment: @RituSumanMohanty i checked your method.. it showing itemCount but why item not showing in adapter

Comment: Can you post you XML file for items

Comment: @RituSumanMohanty yeah. i updated

Comment: Make item height and width as wrap content

Comment: You are using vertical scrolling or horizontal?

Comment: @RituSumanMohanty Please check again i've updated this in brief.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your code isn't working because of background thread. your fetched data is in background thread.They are not in the main thread.

Answer (score -2):

```
 private Context context;
      private List<Card>card;
 public CardAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,List<CategoryModel>card) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, card);
        this.context = context;
        this.card= card;
         }

        public int getCount(){
        return card.size();
    }

        public Card getItem(int position){
        return card.get(position);
    }

        public long getItemId(int position){
        return position;
         }
```

try to do this way, you have missed lots of things

Comment: Sorry, but how? i set flingContainer.setAdapter(cardAdapter); I want to set data to flingContainer.

Comment: flingContainer is your adapter class?

Comment: you can set data on adapter not the view

Comment: what you want to do just tell me

Comment: flingContainer is like recyclerView. i want to set adapter to flingContainer like we set adapter to recyclerview

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202788/discussion-between-rachna-and-pankaj-tungaria).

Comment: cardAdapter = new CardAdapter(this, R.layout.swipe_card_item, cardList);
flingContainer.setAdapter(cardAdapter); set this after this  cardList.add(card);

Comment: then instead of arraylist use List->List<Card> cardList = new ArraList<Card>();
CardAdapter cardAdapter = new CardAdapter(this, R.layout.swipe_card_item, cardList);
flingContainer.setAdapter(cardAdapter);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202857/discussion-between-pankaj-tungaria-and-rachna).